# Alternative Proof about Product Measures and Iterated Integrals

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

**Background**

Theorem 2.36 of Folland's Real Analysis says that if $(X,M,\mu)$ and $(Y,N,\nu)$ are sigma finite measure spaces, and $E\in M\bigotimes N$, then $x\mapsto \nu(E_x)$ and $y\mapsto \mu(E^y)$ are measurable on X and Y and

$$ \mu \times \nu (E) = \int \nu(E_x) d\mu = \int \mu(E^y)d\nu$$

This is a precursor to proving Fubini/Tonelli.  The proof in the book shows that the theorem holds for the algebra of disjoint unions of rectangles, then shows that the set on which this is true is a Monotone class when X,Y are finite measure spaces, then extends to the sigma finite case by dividing up the space and applying the monotone convergence theorem.

**Question**

I have been trying to appreciate why sigma finiteness is an important condition here.  This led me to wonder whether you might be able to prove the above theorem a different way by arguing that the three set-valued functions $\mu \times \nu (E), \int \nu(E_x) d\mu, \int \mu(E^y)d\nu$ are all measures on $M\bigotimes N$ that agree on the algebra $\mathcal{A}$ of disjoint unions of rectangles.  Then in the sigma algebra case, they must be equal on $M\bigotimes N$ by the Hahn-Kolmogorov theorem (I have typed this out below for reference), which says that there is a unique measure that extends the pre-measure defined on the algebra $\mathcal{A}$.

The difficult part seems to be showing that $\nu(E_x)$ is $\mu-$measurable and similarly for $\mu(E^y)$ (without simply reproducing the entire proof from Folland).

edit: One tangible benefit to this would be that you would know whenever $\mu\times\nu(E) < \infty$, then all of these would have to agree, even in the non sigma-finite case.

**Reference** (I called this Hahn-Kolmogorov above).

Let $\mathcal{A\subset \mathcal{P}(X)}$ be an algebra, $\mu_0$ a premeasure on $\mathcal{A}$, and $M$ the sigma algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$.  Then there exists a measure $\mu$ on $M$ extending $\mu_0$.  If $\nu$ is another measure on $M$ extending $\mu_0$, then $\nu(E)\le \mu(E)$ and there is equality when $\mu(E)<\infty$.  If $\mu_0$ is sigma finite, then the extension is unique.

Comment: Oh - that's different. Yes, the measrability seems like the tricky part; I'll undelete my answer if I come up with anything. I _suspect_ the answer is no...

Comment: Good question, wish there were an answer since I also tried this line of proof and failed. I don't think it helps much, but H-K theorem only requires the pre-measure defined on a semi-ring i.e. the "rectangles" in the Cartesian product $M \times N$